# Retrieve image properties from picture array

Tags: c#, date, properties, time, photo

I am currently working on a Windows Forms application with C#. I would like to know how I can retrieve the date and time the image was created. I checked for solutions online, and found references to PropertyItem but I do not
understand how to use it.

My code below takes the photos from a folder and displays them in a picture array.
How can i display the date and time the picture was created in a MessageBox when it is clicked?

```
    // Function to add PictureBox Controls
    private void AddControls(int cNumber)
    {
        imgArray = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[cNumber]; // assign number array 
        for (int i = 0; i < cNumber; i++)
        {
            imgArray[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox(); // Initialize one variable
        }
        // When call this function you determine number of controls
    }

    private void ClickImage(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // On Click: load (ImageToShow) with (Tag) of the image
        ImageToShow = ((System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox)sender).Tag.ToString();
        // then view this image on the form (frmView)

        PrivacyDefenderTabControl.SelectedIndex = 5;
        LogsPhotosPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageToShow);
        LogsPhotosPictureBox.Left = (this.Width - LogsPhotosPictureBox.Width) / 15;
    }

    private void ImagesInFolder()
    {
        FileInfo FInfo;
        // Fill the array (imgName) with all images in any folder 
        imgName = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\Faces");
        // How many Picture files in this folder
        NumOfFiles = imgName.Length;
        imgExtension = new string[NumOfFiles];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFiles; i++)
        {
            FInfo = new FileInfo(imgName[i]);
            imgExtension[i] = FInfo.Extension; // We need to know the Extension
        }
    }

    private void ShowFolderImages()
    {
        int Xpos = 27;
        int Ypos = 8;
        Image img;
        Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback =
            new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        MyProgress.Visible = true;
        MyProgress.Minimum = 0;
        MyProgress.Maximum = NumOfFiles;
        MyProgress.Value = 0;
        MyProgress.Step = 1;
        string[] Ext = new string[] { ".GIF", ".JPG", ".BMP", ".PNG" };
        AddControls(NumOfFiles);
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFiles; i++)
        {
            switch (imgExtension[i].ToUpper())
            {
                case ".JPG":
                case ".BMP":
                case ".GIF":
                case ".PNG":
                    img = Image.FromFile(imgName[i]); // or img = new Bitmap(imgName[i]);
                    imgArray[i].Image = img.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
                    img = null;
                    if (Xpos > 360) // six images in a line
                    {
                        Xpos = 27; // leave eight pixels at Left 
                        Ypos = Ypos + 72;  // height of image + 8
                    }
                    imgArray[i].Left = Xpos;
                    imgArray[i].Top = Ypos;
                    imgArray[i].Width = 64;
                    imgArray[i].Height = 64;
                    imgArray[i].Visible = true;
                    // Fill the (Tag) with name and full path of image
                    imgArray[i].Tag = imgName[i];
                    imgArray[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickImage);
                    this.LogsTabPage.Controls.Add(imgArray[i]);
                    Xpos = Xpos + 72; // width of image + 8
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    MyProgress.PerformStep();
                    break;
            }
        }
        MyProgress.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Image`, once loaded, has no relationship whatsoever with its original file. If, when the user clicks, you're able to retrieve the original filename of the picture, you can use:

```
var lastEditDate = File.GetLastWriteTime("file.jpg");
```

Alternatively, if you already use `FileInfo` instances, you can use:

```
var lastEditDate = new FileInfo("file.jpg").LastWriteTime;
```

Since you can't derive from `Image`, as its constructor is internal, you can keep a `Dictionary<Image,string>` somewhere, populate it when the images are loaded, then retrieve the path relative of the clicked image through a lookup.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the date and time directly from the actual file? how can i do it?

Comment: @David Am I misunderstanding something? My post illustrates how to do it.

Comment: Sorry but how can you output this result in a messagebox? i tried ==> MessageBox.Show(var lastEditDate = new FileInfo(ImageToShow).LastWriteTime);

Comment: @David I assume that `ImageToShow` is a string, in that case you would do: `MessageBox.Show(File.GetLastWriteTime(ImageToShow).ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

At least jpeg files have meta data attached. Please not: it might be attached, but you can't ensure it's there.

You are already reading the image (Image.FromFile) and the resulting object supports the method [GetPropertyItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getpropertyitem.aspx). With that property you can read out meta data. There are a list of available [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id.aspx) (0x0132 should be date and time) and a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7.aspx).